# How to give an NSPopover focus when NSStatusItem is clicked?

Tags: swift, nsstatusitem, nspopover, nsstatusbar

I am building a macOS menubar app in Swift, using an `NSStatusItem`, which opens an `NSPopover` when the `NSStatusItem`'s button is clicked.

How can I also give the `NSPopover` focus? Currently, the user needs to click on the popover to focus it, but I want to grab focus programmatically.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to call `makeKey()` on the owning window.

This can be done either from the main `NSApplicationDelegate`, e.g.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

     // Other setup

     popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
}
```

Or from the relevant `NSViewController`, e.g.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    view.window?.makeKey()
}
```

Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419368-makekey)